# GIT: Create a merged version of a file from two branches

Tags: git

Id't like to create merged version of a file from two branches with 3-way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch

`git branch new_branch`

`git checkout new_branch`

`git merge old_branch1`

`git merge old_branch2`

new_branch contains merged version now and old_branch1 and old_branch2 contain previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

From the current branch, create a new branch:

`git checkout -b new_branch`

After, make merge with another branch:

`git merge old_branch`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that merging is about *combining work.*  I think it helps if, for instance, you think about it as, e.g.:

> *Alice did some work on her files, and Bob did some work on his files, and now Alice, or Bob, or maybe even some third person Carol, wants to* combine *these two lines of work.*

Git generally deals with whole *commits* at a time, not with individual files.  If you run `git merge`, you will merge *commits*, not *files*.  That is, you can `git checkout` Alice's latest commit, then run `git merge Bob`, and Git will find where Alice and Bob started, see what they did to *all* the files, and combine *all* of that.

If you really want to do a three-way merge of *only one* file, you need to obtain three versions of that file.  That, after all, is what a three-way merge is about: obtaining three versions of every file that is to be merged, then using those three input versions to come up with a final, merged version.

The three inputs to a file-level merge operation are:

- The `--ours` version of the file.  If you were to `git checkout Alice` (to get onto branch Alice), that would be Alice's latest.
- The `--theirs` version of the file.  If you were to run `git merge Bob` (to merge from branch Bob), that would be Bob's latest.
- The merge base version of the file.  That's the version of the file that both Alice and Bob started with.  This is the hard part: which version of the file *did* Alice and Bob both start with?

Finding the merge base—and having that merge base get used for *all* the files, not just one—is what `git merge` does for you.  When you run `git merge`, Git uses the history—the commits in the repository—to find the merge base *commit*, i.e., the best shared commit on both branches.  If we recall that every commit automatically remembers its own parent, we can see how this works:

```
             o--o--A   <-- alice
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             o--o--B   <-- bob
```

Alice and Bob both started from commit `*`.  Alice has since made three commits on *her* branch and Bob has made three commits on *his*.  I've labeled Alice's latest as commit `A`, and Bob's latest as commit `B`, here, though of course both of those—and commit `*` as well—have some big ugly hash ID as their actual names.

Commit `*` is on *both* branches, and since it's a *shared* commit and commits are permanent read-only snapshots of *all* files, obviously Alice and Bob both had the same contents in *every* file at that time.  The `git merge` command will therefore take *every* file from commit `*` and compare each such file to *every* file in commit `A`.  Whatever has changed here, Alice has changed.  Then Git will compare every file from `*` with every file in commit `B`.  Whatever has changed here, Bob has changed.

The `git merge` command will now, for each file that is changed in either `A` or `B` as compared to `*`, *combine* the changes to each file.  That is, if Alice and Bob *both* changed `README.md`, Git will combine the changes.  If Alice changed `alice.txt` and Bob didn't, Git will just take Alice's changes.  If Bob changed `blue.py` and Alice didn't, Git will just take Bob's changes.

Having combined all these changes—assuming this combining all works—Git will apply the combined changes to whatever was in `*`.  The resulting files are now suitable to make a *new* commit.  The new commit is a *merge commit*, which is special only because it has two parents instead of the usual one: instead of remembering *my parent is commit A* or *my parent is commit B*, the new commit remembers both:

```
             o--o--A
            /       \
...--o--o--*         M
            \       /
             o--o--B
```

The new commit `M` goes onto whichever branch you have checked out right now.  If that's branch `alice`, the result is:

```
             o--o--A
            /       \
...--o--o--*         M   <-- alice (HEAD)
            \       /
             o--o--B   <-- bob
```

If you start by making a *new* branch—e.g., `carol`—that *also* points to commit `A` first:

```
             o--o--A   <-- alice, carol (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             o--o--B   <-- bob
```

then the new commit `M` changes the name `carol` to point to `M`:

```
             o--o--A   <-- alice
            /       \
...--o--o--*         M   <-- carol (HEAD)
            \       /
             o--o--B   <-- bob
```

Remember that *all* the files in `M` are the result of combining *all* the changes.  The tricky part was finding *changes*, because commits are snapshots—and the trick to doing this was to find snapshot `*`, the merge base.  Git then compared snapshot `*` to snapshot `A`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-A>    # what Alice changed
```

and repeated this for snapshot `B`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> <hash-of-B>    # what Bob changed
```

The merge then combined these changes, for *all* files in the three snapshots, to build merge commit `M`, which goes onto the current branch: the one with `HEAD` attached to it.

#### Conclusion #1

To merge *all* the files in `A` and `B` without affecting any other branch, you can create a *new* branch pointing to either commit `A` or commit `B`, then run `git merge` with any name or hash ID that specifies the other of the two commits.  If the merge succeeds, your new merge commit `M` will point back to both `A` and `B` and will be exclusively on your new branch.

To merge all the files in `A` and `B` while putting the new merge commit into branch `alice` (currently commit `A`) or `bob` (currently commit `B`), check out the desired branch and run `git merge` with the name of the other branch.  If the merge succeeds, your new merge commit `M` will point back to both `A` and `B`, just as for the other case, but this time the merge commit will be on `alice` or `bob`, rather than being on the new branch you didn't create.

#### Conclusion #2

If you really, truly, only want to merge *one* file from commits `A` and `B`, you can't use `git merge` to do that: it does too much; it merges *all* the files.  There is a Git command that can merge one file:

```
git merge-file
```

will do the job.  But it needs *three* input files.  It needs a merge base version of the file whose changes you want to combine.  Find the merge base version, plus the two other versions you'd like to combine.  Put them into three files, e.g., `file.base`, `file.mine`, and `file.theirs`.  Then run:

```
git merge-file file.mine file.base file.theirs
```

Git will compare `file.base` to `file.mine` to see what *you* changed, and compare `file.base` to `file.theirs` to see what *they* changed.  Then it will try to combine these two changes, applying the combined changes to `file.base`, and writing the result into `file.mine`.

This is, of course, exactly what `git merge` does for *every* file.  It's just that `git merge` finds the three files *for* you, and automates all of this work.

Comment: I have a tool that receives the file in question as input. But the tool is different for each branch, thus the file format as well. When I tried to merge a branch with the old format, I could not merge the file, so I took --ours and deferred the work for later. When the time arrived, some parts of the file could be merged (the parts where the format did not differ), and I needed the merged versions of those parts. I did what other answers recommended, which was to create another branch to do the merge, take the file, discard the branch, and do the rest of the adaptation by hand.

Comment: To do the rest of the "merge", I had to create a tool that indicated me the differences between the old file and the new file.